# find a solution for $t^2y''-2y=3t^2-1$ given that $y_1=t^2, y_2=t^{-1}$ satisfy the homogeneous equaiton

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I need to find a solution for $t^2y''-2y=3t^2-1$ given that $y_1=t^2, y_2=t^{-1}$ satisfy the homogeneous equaiton, so that's what I did:

$$Y = u_1t^2+u_2t^{-1}$$

See that the wronskian is: $W(y_1,y_2) = -3$

Then the solutions are given by:

$$u_1' = -\frac{t^{-1}(3t^2-1)}{-3}\implies u_1 = \frac{t^2}{2}-3\ln t$$

$$u_2' = \frac{t^2(3t^2-1)}{-3}\implies u_2 = \frac{-t^5}{5}+\frac{t^3}{9}$$

$u_1$ [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20-t%5E(-1)*(3t%5E2-1)%2F(-3)), $u_2$ [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20t%5E2*(3t%5E2-1)%2F(-3))

however, when I multiply them back at $Y$, I get [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(t%5E3%2F9-t%5E5%2F5)*t%5E(-1)%2B(t%5E2%2F2-3ln(t))*t%5E2)  , when I should get $\frac{1}{2}+t^2\ln t$. Can someobdy spot an error?

UPDATE:

I did everything wrong, I need to divide by $t^2$ in order to use these formulas. That's what I did now:

$$u_1 = \int -\frac{t^{-1}\left(3-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)}{-3}\ dt = \ln t +\frac{1}{6t^2}$$
$$u_2 = \int \frac{t^2\left(3-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)}{-3}\ dt = \frac{1}{3}(t-t^3)$$

$u_1$ [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20-t%5E(-1)*(3-1%2Ft%5E2)%2F(-3)), $u_2$ [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20t%5E2*(3-1%2Ft%5E2)%2F(-3))

The $Y$ is giving me [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(ln(t)%2B1%2F(6t%5E2))*t%5E2%2B(t%2F3-t%5E3%2F3)*t%5E(-1))
but this isn't still $\frac{1}{2}+t^2\ln t$

Comment: @Moo you're right, I updated my question with the correction. Can you spot any error? I almost got the answer but something is wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please see my answer to one of your other questions which explains why you still have a correct answer.